# Iterating over rows and columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to fill mean values of columns for all NaNs values in the column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

table = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,np.nan],
                  'B':[3,np.nan, np.nan],
                  'C':[4,5,6]})

def impute_missing_values(table):
    for column in table:
        for value in column:
            if value  == 'NaN':
                value = column.mean(skipna=True)
            else: 
                value = value
impute_missing_values(table)
table
```

Why I am getting an error for this code?

Comment: do you mean `'non-NaN'` values? Nan is akin to a blank value, won't return any mean values. Plus, you're using `'skipna=True'` which would exclude all NaN values. Hence the error.

Comment: Yes.. Non NaN values.. I want to fill the NaNs with the mean value of the non- NaN values in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I am adding this as another answer because this isn't something I recommend at all.  Using pandas methods vectorizes operations for better performance. 
 Using loops is not recommended when possible to avoid.

However, here is a quick fix to your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

table = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,np.nan],
                  'B':[3,np.nan, np.nan],
                  'C':[4,5,6]})

def impute_missing_values(df):
    for column in df:
        for idx, value in df[column].iteritems():
            if math.isnan(value):
                df.loc[idx,column] = df[column].mean(skipna=True)
            else: 
                pass
    return df

impute_missing_values(table)
table
```

Output:

```
     A    B  C
0  1.0  3.0  4
1  2.0  3.0  5
2  1.5  3.0  6
```

Comment: Why did you choose math.isnan ? I mean what is wrong with: if value  == 'NaN': ??

Comment: I don't think value == 'NaN' will work, due to the value is dtype float.  However,  maybe wrong.

Answer (score 6):

IIUC:

```
table.fillna(table.mean())
```

Output:

```
     A    B  C
0  1.0  3.0  4
1  2.0  3.0  5
2  1.5  3.0  6
```

Comment: @gofvonx And indeed the per-mean column is what `table.mean()` will return. This is correct.

Comment: Mean calculate column wise in pandas by default and then pandas uses index alignment to place means in correct columns.

Comment: Yes. we have a fillna function. But I want to inderstand what is the problem in the above code?

Comment: Actually I want to understand how to iterate columns and their values..

Answer (score 0):

You can try the SimpleImputer from scikit learn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html#sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer) using the mean option.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

table = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,np.nan],
                  'B':[3,np.nan, np.nan],
                  'C':[4,5,6]})
print(table, '\n')
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
table_means = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(table), columns = {'C','B','A'})
print(table_means)
```

The print commands results in:

```
     A    B  C
0  1.0  3.0  4
1  2.0  NaN  5
2  NaN  NaN  6 

     A    C    B
0  1.0  3.0  4.0
1  2.0  3.0  5.0
2  1.5  3.0  6.0
```

To correct your code (as per my comment below):

```
def impute_missing_values(table):
    for column in table:
        table.loc[:,column] = np.where(table[column].isna(), table[column].mean(), table[column])
    return table
```

Comment: Thanks @ Jorge.. Actually I am aware about this method. Just that I am looking to fix my code and not necessarily the outcome per se.

Comment: Actually, from achieving the outcome perspective- there is another one: from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer.

Comment: In that case, you can not compare strings to numbers. NaN is basically a number when the datatype is a number (float or int). Your value=='NaN' statement, is trying to compare the 'number' NaN to the string 'NaN'. I edit my answer to use np.where within your function.