# How can I replace missing values using python loops in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({A:[1,2,'NaN',3,4,'Nan'],B:[2,'NaN',3,'NaN',9]})
```

Now the issue is I have to replace `NaN` values by defining a function and using loops to solve them

how can I do that?

Comment: Doing this with loops is clumsy. Why do you insist on it?

Comment: You can't have a dataframe like that. `A` and `B` are not defined and the columns don't match in length. Also, are you sure that you have `'NaN'` *string* values? Please show the expected result.

Comment: Mistakenly I missed out a value in column B, it is B: [2,'NaN',3,'NaN',9,6], I wanted to know how would it look like if it had to be solved using a defined function. And how do we define columns A and B can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine why this would ever be done in practice explicitly with loops, but it is actually quite straightforward. iterate through columns and rows, replacing values as you go.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def painful_fillna(df, fillvalue=0):
    df = df.copy()
    for col in df.columns:
        for i, value in enumerate(df[col].values):
            if np.isnan(value):
                df[col][i] = fillvalue
    return(df)

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,'NaN',3,4,'NaN'],'B':[2,'NaN',3,'NaN',9, 'NaN']})
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
painful_fillna(df)
```

The average runtime of the above function on my machine is 1.05 ms. The average runtime of `df.fillna(0)` is 278 µs.

I've addressed a few issues above as well: 
 1. A and B were replaced with 'A' and 'B'. 
 2. A missing value was added to B ('NaN')
 3. string 'NaN's were converted to np.NaN

Answer (score -1):

Here is a similar question with several answers: [Iterating over rows and columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996433/iterating-over-rows-and-columns-in-pandas/53998299?noredirect=1#comment94840712_53998299)

p.s. You can search this site first with different terms and try to find an answer.